# Swift CPU hogging

Tags: arrays, swift, sprite-kit, cpu-usage

I was testing background objects execution, which is just a few dozen `SKSpriteNodes` in an array moving upwards from the bottom of the screen and being removed after going above the top of the screen. They also move horizontally on a sine wave. I am storing nodes in `backNodeArray` and their current horizontal speed in `backHorSpeedArray: [Float]`.

On appearance of first nodes on the screen, the CPU utilization on iPhone 4S reaches 100%, and when the number becomes more or less stable at about 25 nodes at any given moment, the FPS is already below 35.

I've checked for hogs with Time Profiler and found that the single line of code is responsible for over 55% of execution time.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    else if (state == 1) {
        if (self.backNodeArray.count > 0) {
            for i in 0...self.backNodeArray.count-1 {
                self.backHorSpeedArray[i]++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, every time that the update function is called, every item in `self.backHorSpeedArray` is incremented, and that takes more than half of execution time!?

When that line is commented out, the CPU never reaches 100% and FPS is 60 with no oscillations.

What is going on here? I could have a variable memorizing how many steps it was since the beginning of the game and then add the 'read-only' value from array for when it's required which may solve the performance issue, but why is this so CPU intensive?

Comment: store count in an int and cache the array in a local var. This will reduxe some overhead of getting the properties every iteration

Comment: What I don't understand is how it can work out position.x using sin and division for every node in the background, but can't increment members of the array by 1...